# Running Genymotion in the cloud - EC2 Instance

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, genymotion

I am looking to test my application on an android device but also need to be able to install things like `nodejs`, `mongo`, `ruby` to name but a few. Basically my application sends data to an endpoint (mongo) and then i assert that they are there with some cucumber tests.

So i have come across Genymotion On Demand which looks like it could work but was wondering how i can use the app to send data to an endpoint on another EC2 instance and also control the app (say restart it via the command line), again in this separate instance

Has anyone done this or can point me in the right direction please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have no problem contacting the server instance from the Genymotion on demand instance using its private IP address if it is in the same network, or its public IP address otherwise.

For the second part of the question: from your linux instance (with `mongo` `nodejs` & `ruby`), you can use `adb` to interact with the Genymotion instance. This will allow you to control the app, inside the instance, using 'am' command line tool. See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#am on how to start your application by sending an intent. If you need a tutorial on how to start the `adb` server in the Genymotion on demand instance, please see https://www.genymotion.com/help/on-demand/tutorial/enable-disable-adb/.

On a side note, you can even dynamically spawn/shutdown Genymotion On Demand instances from your linux instance using the AWS SDK or cli.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll take a look into what you have raised